# Save edited listbox items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, save, listboxitem

In my wpf app, I wrote code for editing contents of listbox items. Edit process is working fine. After editing I want to save those changes in listbox itself. How could I do that?

My listbox consist of Horizontal stackpanel of six textboxes.

As I used templates in my app, my code is,

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate tmpl= (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate");
        if (listBox1.ItemTemplate == tmpl)
        {
            tmpl = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("EditableDataTemplate");
            listBox1.ItemTemplate = tmpl;
            this.EditButton.Content = "Done Editing";
        }
        else
        {
            tmpl = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate");
            listBox1.ItemTemplate = tmpl;
            this.EditButton.Content = "Edit";
        }

        // I just want to add here something to save those contents.
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want to save those contents?
And what do you mean with "_I want to save those changes in listbox itself._" ??

Comment: On that place only where I changed. so when I visit next time, there should be updated contents there.

Comment: Do you have some bindings or did you create the List in Code-Behind?

Comment: Yes. My listbox is bound to my Harvest account. so Data in listbox comes from Harvest. Actually edit works fine. I just want to know, How should I save those changes when click on button.

Comment: If you have a ViewModel/Model bound to the view the changes you make are automatically saved if you bind to a property of it.
If that's not the case then I can't help you because I don't know how you bind the data and I also don't know how harvest works...
sorry.